# Codility Brackets challenge performance issue

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, implementation

Trying out a simple codility challenge (check that a string of {} characters is well-formed) I have become stumbled by the fact that my solution has a terrible performance score and even times out on some of their test cases.

The specification is "return 1 if well-formed, 0 otherwise":

```
class Solution {
public int solution(String S) {

    Deque<String> stack = new LinkedList<String>();
    while (S.length() > 0) {
        String firstChar = S.substring(0, 1);
        if (isOpenBracket(firstChar)) {
            stack.addFirst(firstChar);
        }
        else {
            String matchingOpen = closedToOpen(firstChar);
            if (matchingOpen == null) return 0;

            String topOfStack = stack.pollFirst();
            if (!matchingOpen.equals(topOfStack)) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        S = S.substring(1);
    }
    return stack.isEmpty() ? 1 : 0;
}

public boolean isOpenBracket(String s) {
    return ("{".equals(s) || "[".equals(s) || "(".equals(s));
}

public String closedToOpen(String closed) {
    if ("}".equals(closed)) return "{";
    if ("]".equals(closed)) return "[";
    if (")".equals(closed)) return "(";
    return null;
}
}
```

At first I thought the culprit to be addFirst / pollFirst actually appending at the far end of the linkedlist, but that's not the case (changing to add/pollLast yields the same score profile actually).

I can see that using chars instead of strings would speed up things, but I don't think it too be relevant enough to timeout the tests (expected time <3 secs, runtime > 8 secs)...

My last guess would be the fact that the helpers method reallocate the constants on each call... but still, is that so big of an impact?

Any ideas?

Comment: substring will eat you alive

Comment: Get rid of the substring calls.

Comment: Are they THAT bad? What if I just take charAt, would that still be slow as a brick?

Comment: All of you are right. Changing to charAt in a for fixed it. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that substring called on a string of length `n` has cost `O(n)` because it makes a copy.  Instead of constantly copying the string, you want to keep one string and access each character.

Comment: Got it. It's pretty obvious when you think of it. I know I should stop doing these things when I only get 3 hours of sleep ^^. Cheers.